# Adding an authentication with SecurityContext.xml on Spring Boot

Tags: xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, illegalargumentexception

I can't add a page role with `SecurityContext.xml`.
What Can I do for this?

Worked push configuration with configuration class.
But XML Configuration Not Works:

## My XML Configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

## This Configuration make this error in runtime.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression 'ROLE_USER'at org.springframework.security.access.expression.ExpressionUtils.evaluateAsBoolean(ExpressionUtils.java:30) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:52) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at

Comment: `access` requires an expression not just the name of a role. Something like `access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not right:

```
    <authentication-provider>
       <user-service>
          <user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
       </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
```

For authentication-provider, you need to give a reference to a bean that is an AuthenticationProvider.

e.g.

```
<authentication-manager >
    <authentication-provider ref="myAuthProvider"/>
</authentication-manager>
```